# how can I keep track of the owner of each nft in my contract in Cadence?

Tags: onflow-cadence

Someone suggested I should aggregate events in an external db but I'm trying to avoid that and keep all the info in the contract. Any ideas? -spacepluk

Answer (score -1):

There’s no way to do that on-chain. NFTs in Cadence are resources stored in user’s account instead of the contract (“decentralized storage” / ownership instead of “ledger-style” / centralized storage). Users can freely do whatever they want with their data, including transferring it. That’s not a function of the contract. It’s different by design. -Bastian